# Solve Query Failures Regarding ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL Mode

Tags: mysql, sql

From https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/

> “Hey, what’s going on with my applications? I installed a newer version of MySQL. I have queries that perfectly run with the older version and now I have a lot of errors.”
>
> This is a question some customers have asked me after upgrading MySQL. In this article, we’ll see what one of the most frequent causes of this issue is, and how to solve it.
>
> We are talking about this error:

My error is the same:

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'ebenlizy_inventorycontrol.sales_orders.orderId'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

my query is

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"
  SELECT
     Sum(sales_order_details.quantity) AS Quantity,
     (SELECT buyingPrice from items INNER JOIN sales_order_details ON items.stockId = sales_order_details.stockId WHERE sales_order_details.orderId = sales_orders.orderId) AS buyingPrice,
 sales_order_details.price
  FROM sales_orders 
  JOIN sales_order_details ON sales_orders.orderId = sales_order_details.orderId  
  WHERE MONTH(sales_orders.orderDate)='$month' 
    and YEAR(sales_orders.orderDate)='$year' 
    AND sales_orders.branchId =$id 
    AND salesStatus=1") 
or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and your desired output in table format

Comment: I'm curious; the start of your question is written like a blog post. Are you writing a blog post about this? Did you get half way through your blog post and then realize you didn't actually understand the subject matter so you hit up SO with a question? Does the author of any answer here get a credit in this blog as being the person who supplied the info, or will it be presented as your work? If it's being credited with a link to here then I'll I undelete my answer. If SO contributions are being used as source material without credit, that's a poor show, and I'll leave it deleted

Comment: The aggregation part is not the only issue in your query. There is also the subquery in the select clause that is likely to return more than one row.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)